# Error in MySQL 5.1 stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am new to stored procedure

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_MyNewTable
(IN Mod nvarchar(50),IN Did int,IN startdate datetime,IN enddate datetime)
BEGIN
Declare DateDuration int,
SET actstatus=1,
SET DateDuration =  SELECT  DATEDIFF(startdate,enddate) as Datediff
insert into mytable (Duration,Module,Deptid,taskstartdate,activestatus) values       (DateDuration,Mod,did,enddate,startdate,actstatus)
 Select * from mytable 
 END //
 DELIMITER;
```

**Getting error if I execute this:**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near sp_MyNewTable (IN Mod nvarchar(50),IN Did int,IN startdate
>   datetime,IN enddate datetime)

MYSQL version is **MYSQL 5.1**

Comment: MySQL 4.x does not support stored procedures.

Comment: Stored procedures were introduced in MySQL 5. Besides … are you really still on MySQL 4.x? Based on that, I'd assume that your OS is horribly outdated and has gaping security holes.

Comment: by the way is that code is the right one for myql above 5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_MyNewTable`(IN `Mod` VARCHAR(50),
                                 IN `Did` INT,
                                 IN `startdate` DATETIME,
                                 IN `enddate` DATETIME)
BEGIN
  DECLARE `DateDuration` INT;
  DECLARE `actstatus` DATETIME;
  SET `actstatus` := 1, `DateDuration` := DATEDIFF(`startdate`, `enddate`);
  INSERT INTO `mytable`
  (`Duration`, `Module`, `Deptid`, `taskenddate`, `taskstartdate`, `activestatus`)
  VALUES
  (`DateDuration`, `Mod`, `Did`, `enddate`, `startdate`, `actstatus`);
  SELECT * FROM `mytable`;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/dd165/1)</kbd>

Comment: how to see the result of this procedure